# Why am I getting "Duplicate local variable error" here?

Tags: java, jsp

I have this code where I am trying to send an email using JAVA Mail API. When running this code in eclipse, I am getting error as "**Multiple annotations found at this line:Duplicate local variable session**". I have declared session variable only once then why I am getting this error?

```
try{ 
    String host="smtp.gmail.com";
    String to="abc@gmail.com"; 
    final String user="xyz@gmail.com";  
    final String password="*********"; 
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();  
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host );  
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
    }  
    });  
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,  
                             new InternetAddress(to));  

   message.setSubject("Thank you subscriber");  
   message.setContent("<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>+name+</td></tr><tr><td>Address</td><td>+Addr+</td></tr><tr><td>Age</td><td>+age+</td></tr><tr><td>Qualification</td><td>+Qual+</td></tr><tr><td>Percentage</td><td>+Persent+</td></tr><tr><td>Passout</td><td>+Year+</td></tr></table>","text/html");

  Transport.send(message);  
    System.out.println("message sent....");  
 }
catch (MessagingException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}  
finally {}
```

This is my servlet which I am using.

```
package com.registration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegistrationController
 */
public class RegistrationController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegistrationController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String name = request.getParameter("fullname");
        String Addr = request.getParameter("address");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String Qual = request.getParameter("qual");
        String Persent = request.getParameter("percent");
        String Year = request.getParameter("yop");
        if(name.isEmpty()||Addr.isEmpty()||age.isEmpty()||Qual.isEmpty()||Persent.isEmpty()||Year.isEmpty())
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registration.jsp");
            out.println("<font color=red>OOPS!! YOU MISSED OUT SOME FIELDS. FILL THEM AGAIN</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Put all this code in a Java source file, where it belongs, rather than a JSP. Inside a JSP, there is already an implicit local variable named session, representing the HTTP session. JSPs should just not have any single line of Java code. They are view components, and should thus only generate HTML, using the JSP EL, the JSTL and other tag libraries.

Comment: Thank you @JB Nizet. I am aware of the fact that JSP should NOT have JAVA codes mostly. but  As I was confused like I couldn't decide where to put the email sending code in the servlet,SO instead i tried to put this all in the final JSP. I am not sure where I can put this code so that as soon as user submits correct data, he/she gets an immidiate email.

Comment: Well, call the methos sending the email from the else block of your doPost() method: that's the method handling the submission, ad that's where you know the submission is valid, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsp has an inbuilt session variable that you can actually use. So since you are reusing it you are getting the duplicate error.

This is the equivalent of doing Session session=request.getSession() in a servlet;

Comment: Your code belongs in a servlet or a separate java class actually not in a jsp file. JSP should deal more with generating the UI.

Comment: Yes @Joey I am aware of this fact that JSP should not be stuffed with java codes. As this is just out of curiosity I tried to give an attempt how to send an email so I am just doing it. next time onwards I will keep my code in a different class...btw Any suggestion how to use that session? How should I modify that code?

Comment: Put all this code in a servlet class and there you can use the session code as is.

Comment: Thank you @Joey...I definitely agree with your answer. I have a doubt though. As I am confused like I couldn't decide where to put this email sending code in the servlet, I instead tried to put this all in the final JSP. Can you help me out where can I put this code in the servlet. Please see the edit in the question.

Comment: In your else block should be fine

Comment: Add it before the Request dispatcher